# Framelayout não mostra meus TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

Meu **Framelayout** do nada bugou e não está mostrando mais os dados recebidos do Json no meu **TexView** na parte do **Header**. Mesmo eu adicionando um text ele não mostra nada.

- **XML:**

  ```
  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView_header_book"
          android:layout_width= "match_parent"
          android:layout_height="84dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="410dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:src="@drawable/header_book"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/custom_view_loja"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:maxLines="2"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_loja"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:shadowColor="@color/black"
          android:shadowDx="1"
          android:shadowDy="1"
          android:shadowRadius="2"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/custom_view_shopping"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginBottom="245dp"
          android:shadowColor="@color/black"
          android:shadowDx="1"
          android:shadowDy="1"
          android:shadowRadius="2"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_shopping" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/custom_view_competencia"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="219dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_competencia"
          android:shadowColor="@color/black"
          android:shadowDx="1"
          android:shadowDy="1"
          android:shadowRadius="2"/>
  </FrameLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/custom_view_information_container"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingRight="30dp" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/custom_view_book_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/custom_view_book_text_data"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

              <FrameLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

                  <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/imageView_aluguel_shopping"
                      android:layout_width="35dp"
                      android:layout_height="40dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                      android:layout_gravity="left"
                      android:src="@drawable/aluguel_shopping" />

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textView_aluguel_icon_title"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="14dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                      android:gravity="left"
                      android:text="Aluguel"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_aluguel_icon"
                      android:textStyle="bold"/>

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/custom_view_valor_aluguel"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="left"
                      android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                      android:singleLine="true"
                      android:text="R$ 1.000.000"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_valorAluguel"
                      android:textStyle="bold"/>

                  <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/imageView_venda_shopping"
                      android:layout_width="35dp"
                      android:layout_height="40dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                      android:layout_gravity="right"
                      android:src="@drawable/venda_shopping" />


                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textView_vendas_icon_title"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="14dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="142dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                      android:gravity="right"
                      android:text="Venda"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_venda_icon"
                      android:textStyle="bold"/>

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/custom_view_valor_venda"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="right"
                      android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
                      android:gravity="right"
                      android:singleLine="true"
                      android:text="R$1.000.000"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_valorVenda"
                      android:textStyle="bold"/>
              </FrameLayout>

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/custom_view_valor_aluguelMensal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_valorAluguelMensal" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/custom_view_valor_aluguelAnual"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_valorAluguelAnual" />


              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/custom_view_valor_vendaMensal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_valorVendaMensal" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/custom_view_valor_vendaAnual"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_valorVendaAnual" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/badge_custoOcupacao_valor"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/overlay_custoOcupacao_valor"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

          </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignRight="@id/custom_view_book_background"
      android:layout_below="@id/custom_view_information_container" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:rotation="20" >
      </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente está faltando o namespace no seu FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: essa resposta não foi útil para mim.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema.

- O que estava acontecendo era o seguinte:
  Eu adicionei a seguinte tag em um **TextView** e **ImageView**, porém por algum motivo ela "**buga**" o layout e acontece os problemas que citei na pergunta.

**Então bastou remover o** :

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```